# How do the lists of close votes in the history and in the close vote queue differ?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

I recently had a question that was intermittently closed. When [looking at the question history](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/201061/timeline), the list of close votes differs from the list when looking at the list of voters in the [review queue](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/review/close/80638). Two close votes appear only in the question history, one appears only in the review queue (which also only has four close votes overall, not five).

Does the review queue only register close votes made via the queue, while the question registers votes from the question close link and the queue? Is it possible to vote close but miss the time window before some other vote was registered, and have the vote then not appear on the closing list in the history?

Comment: Not all close votes come from a review. Users can vote to close outside the review.

Answer (score 10):

#### The review queue history is the history of reviews only.

There are two places to vote to close a question: the question page and the review queue. If you vote to close while performing a close vote review, it will show up in the review history. If you vote to close from the question page, it will only be seen if the question is successfully closed, and only in (up to) two places: the question timeline, and if the question is *not* yours, the close voters will be shown in the closed banner.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasMarkov. What is puzzling me is that one of the close votes from the review does not show up in the question page history. How does that happen -- is it because someone else just shortly before got the 5th close vote in, and it only will list the first five in the history?

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin It’s most likely they voted to close from the queue, then later retracted the close vote, rather than some sort of highly coincidental race condition.

Comment: (Which is what I did on that question. I VTC’d for more details, you provided more details, I thought about what an answer might look like, and decided the question didn’t need any further details, so I retracted my close vote and answered the question.)

Comment: Close/reopen votes can also age away, so you won't see any evidence of old, unsuccessful votes except in the review queue item (unless you're a moderator). However, the linked question is too new to have any aged away votes.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Yes, I figured that is what happend with the help of your answer - thank you for both the patience and the explanations. And the answer.